# USB Host Development on Android 2.3 Device

Tags: java, android

I just got a development kit that have a physical two USB Host port and the Android specification says it support USB Host, I am curious about this as USB Host is introduced in Android 3.1, where my kit only have Android 2.3

Does this mean that I can use the API as described here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Comment: Looks like a very strange kit. Maybe it has some special, proprietary USB support classes?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use USB host api in **Android 2.3** as USB host mode is supported in **Android 3.1 and higher**. Even in some of those Device i mean Some Android 3.1 will need root Access to use them in USB Host mode.